# async await data return from backend node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have this function:

```
module.exports = async function(username, password, mongo_uri, cluster, collection) {
    
    let client = new MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    let database = client.db(cluster)
    let collection_name = database.collection(collection)

    
    if (!username || !password || !username && !password) {
        return false
    } else {
        //query mongo
       MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, async function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            collection_name.find({'email': username}).toArray(async function(e,doc){
                if(doc.length === 0) {
                    db.close();
                    return false
                } else {
                    db.close();
                    return true
                }
            });
        })
    }
 }
```

and I have this in the front-end:

```
 let results = await mongo_login_api(username, password, mongo_uri, cluster, collection)
console.log("results")
console.log(results)
```

when I run this function, it doesn't wait for the backend to return anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending anything? Because I don't see you return anything in backend. Check the network tab in dev tools to see what you got.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes, because I had it logging in the backend, and it was returning it, and in the front-end it just logs undefined because it happens before it returns anything

Comment: Try with `return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{}`. And put the body of your function in. When return you can return with `resolve(true)` or `resolve(false)`

Comment: Your using the callback variant's of the lib, use the promise variant instead.  eg.  `MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, function (db) {})` ->  `const db = await MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri)` etc.

Comment: More info -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/

Comment: `if (err) { console.log(err); }`  generally speaking this is the most dangerous & pointless thing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is:

You put all body of your funcion in Promise.

For example:

```
module.exports = function(username, password, mongo_uri, cluster, collection) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let client = new MongoClient(mongo_uri)
       let database = client.db(cluster)
       let collection_name = database.collection(collection)

    
       if (!username || !password || !username && !password) {
          resolve(false)
       } else {
        
        
        //query mongo
       MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, async function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            collection_name.find({'email': username}).toArray(function(e,doc){
                if(doc.length === 0) {
                    db.close();
                    resolve(false)
                } else {
                    db.close();
                    resolve(true) 
                }
            });
        })
      }
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Or just use the Promise returned from Mongo if you don't supply a callback.

Comment: Although this all seems overkill, seen as MongoDB has promises anyway,.  You may as well do -> `if (err) return reject(err)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to promise the `MongoClient.connect` callback to `await` it.

```
module.exports = async function(username, password, mongo_uri, cluster, collection) {
    let client = new MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    let database = client.db(cluster)
    let collection_name = database.collection(collection)

    if (!username || !password || !username && !password) {
        return false
    } else {
        const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            //query mongo
            MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, function(err, db) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                collection_name.find({
                    'email': username
                }).toArray(function(e, doc) {
                    if (doc.length === 0) {
                        db.close();
                        resolve(false)
                    } else {
                        db.close();
                        resolve(true)
                    }
                });
            })
        })
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that if MongoDB can use promises anyway?.  Also your missing the promise constructor here.

Comment: I don't use MongoDB so I didn't know that it already has a promise thanks for the info, I just saw a promising case that needs to be resolved, Also I'm sorry but which constructor did I miss?

Comment: `new Promise((resolve, reject) =>`  This bit is known as the promise constructor, that's how you get `resolve` / `reject`.

Comment: But I didn't miss it, please have a look the code in the `else` condition.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Normally I would put a Promise constructor at the start, and with your indentation been slightly off it was easy to miss.  But this mixing of `async` and Promise constructor just feels wrong, and looks nasty.

Comment: About the indentation, It's one of the most annoying issues on StackOverflow code snippets, and it's hard to spend 5 min aligning all indentations, About "async and Promise constructor just feels wrong, and looks nasty.", That's will be correct if I use `async` inside the promise, and that's not correct, await a promise constructor is a normal case.

Comment: Not saying it wont work, but it not great mixing.   It's easy to handle indentation in SO.    Just use the tripple backticks,  I've updated your post using this..

Comment: Thanks for the triple backticks info.